# Python multiple choice quiz scoring using tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm working in a project for my coding class, its a simple high school beginner class. The assignment is a multiple choice quiz that also counts the number of correct answers. The code uses Tkinter, specifically the Notebook. I'm having trouble tallying up the score. If I set it as a variable, it just returns at 0, when it should show the number increasing when the correct answer is correct. Any help??

```
global total

y=0  
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
n= ttk.Notebook()
f1= ttk.Frame(n)
f2= ttk.Frame(n)
f3= ttk.Frame(n)
f4= ttk.Frame(n)
f5= ttk.Frame(n)
f6= ttk.Frame(n)

window= ttk.Frame(n)


def main(x):
    global total
    n.add(f1, text="One")
    n.add(f2, text="Two")
    n.add(f3, text="Three")
    n.add(f4, text="Four")
    n.add(f5, text="Five")
    n.add(f6, text="Six")

    total= ttk.Label(window, text="0")


    Label(f1, text="What is Tkinter?").grid(row=2,column=2)
    Button(f1, text="Guided User Interface").bind(correct)
    Button(f1, text="Guided User Interface").grid(row=3,column=1)
    Button(f1, text="Variable", command=incorrect).grid(row=3,column=2)
    Button(f1, text="Function", command=incorrect).grid(row=3,column=3)


    Label(f2, text="What is Turtle?").grid(row=2,column=2)
    Button(f2, 
    text="GuidedUserInterface",command=incorrect2).grid(row=3,column=1)
    Button(f2, text="Module", command=correct2).grid(row=3,column=2)
    Button(f2, text="Boolean Value", command=incorrect2).grid(row=3,column=3)

    Label(f3, text="What does the 'Print' command do?").grid(row=2,column=2)
    Button(f3, text="Creater a window",command=incorrect3).grid(row=3,column=1)
    Button(f3, text="Show a message in the Python Shell", command=correct3).grid(row=3,column=2)
    Button(f3, text="Print to the printer", command=incorrect3).grid(row=3,column=3)

    Label(f4, text="What is the moniter?").grid(row=2,column=2)
    Button(f4, text="A display that shows what the computer is doing",command=correct4).grid(row=3,column=1)
    Button(f4, text="A circut board", command=incorrect4).grid(row=3,column=2)
    Button(f4, text="A Program", command=incorrect4).grid(row=3,column=3)


    Label(f5, text="What does the 'from ____ import' command do?").grid(row=2,column=2)
    Button(f5, text="Import an image",command=incorrect5).grid(row=3,column=1)
    Button(f5, text="Import text", command=incorrect5).grid(row=3,column=2)
    Button(f5, text="Import a module", command=correct5).grid(row=3,column=3)

    Label(f6, text="Which of these is a Boolean Value?").grid(row=2,column=2)
    Button(f6, text="Enter",command=incorrect6).grid(row=3,column=1)
    Button(f6, text="Esc", command=incorrect6).grid(row=3,column=2)
    Button(f6, text="True", command=correct6).grid(row=3,column=3)
    return total



def correct():
    global total
    Label(f1, text="Correct").grid(row=1,column=2)
    counter()
def incorrect():
    Label(f1, text="Incorrect").grid(row=1,column=2)

def correct2():
    global total
    Label(f2, text="Correct").grid(row=1,column=2)
    counter()

def incorrect2():
    Label(f2, text="Incorrect").grid(row=1,column=2)

def correct3():
    global total
    Label(f3, text="Correct").grid(row=1,column=2)
    counter()

def incorrect3():
    Label(f3, text="Incorrect").grid(row=1,column=2)

def correct4():
    global total
    Label(f4, text="Correct").grid(row=1,column=2)
    counter()

def incorrect4():
    Label(f4, text="Incorrect").grid(row=1,column=2)

def correct5():
    global total
    Label(f5, text="Correct").grid(row=1,column=2)
    counter()

def incorrect5():
    Label(f5, text="Incorrect").grid(row=1,column=2)

def correct6():
    global total
    Label(f6, text="Correct").grid(row=1,column=2)
    counter()

def incorrect6():
    Label(f6, text="Incorrect").grid(row=1,column=2)


def counter():
    global total
    total['text'] = str(int(total['text']) + 1)


main(y)


n.pack()

n.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a situation where tkinter's Variable Classes would be of help, specifically, the `IntVar` class.  I've reworked your code below to make `total` an `IntVar` but reduced it to three questions to simplify the example:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def main():

    notebook.add(frame1, text="One")
    notebook.add(frame2, text="Two")
    notebook.add(frame3, text="Three")

    Label(frame1, text="What is Tkinter?").grid(row=2, column=2)
    Button(frame1, text="Guided User Interface", command=correct1).grid(row=3, column=1)
    Button(frame1, text="Variable", command=incorrect1).grid(row=3, column=2)
    Button(frame1, text="Function", command=incorrect1).grid(row=3, column=3)

    Label(frame2, text="What is Turtle?").grid(row=2, column=2)
    Button(frame2, text="Guided User Interface", command=incorrect2).grid(row=3, column=1)
    Button(frame2, text="Module", command=correct2).grid(row=3, column=2)
    Button(frame2, text="Boolean Value", command=incorrect2).grid(row=3, column=3)

    Label(frame3, text="What does the 'Print' command do?").grid(row=2, column=2)
    Button(frame3, text="Create a window", command=incorrect3).grid(row=3, column=1)
    Button(frame3, text="Show a message in the Python Shell", command=correct3).grid(row=3, column=2)
    Button(frame3, text="Print to the printer", command=incorrect3).grid(row=3, column=3)

    notebook.pack()

    Label(root, text="Total:").pack()
    Label(root, textvariable=total).pack()

def correct1():
    Label(frame1, text="Correct").grid(row=1, column=2)
    counter()

def incorrect1():
    Label(frame1, text="Incorrect").grid(row=1, column=2)

def correct2():
    Label(frame2, text="Correct").grid(row=1, column=2)
    counter()

def incorrect2():
    Label(frame2, text="Incorrect").grid(row=1, column=2)

def correct3():
    Label(frame3, text="Correct").grid(row=1, column=2)
    counter()

def incorrect3():
    Label(frame3, text="Incorrect").grid(row=1, column=2)

def counter():
    total.set(total.get() + 1)

root = Tk()

total = IntVar()  # defaults to 0

notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)

frame1 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
frame2 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
frame3 = ttk.Frame(notebook)

main()

root.mainloop()
```

You could set the label text explicitly instead of using the `IntVar`, but this seems a classic example of why the Variable Classes exist.